# Get the value of a property of an object Spring Boot Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I get the variable ***statusCode*** that is printed on the image?

```
        Object obj = pjp.proceed();
        
        for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true); 
            Object value = field.get(obj); 
            if (value != null) {
                System.out.println(field.getName() + " = " + value);
                //Print:  presSvcRs = banckofcolombia.checkinvoice.IFX$PresSvcRs@107813f5
            }
```

[image]

Comment: If you can cast obj to IFX class instead of using reflection your code will be much more robust. Maybe IFX class has accessors for statusCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing the fields with reflection, if the IFX class is exposing its fields with getters you could do something like the following:

```
Object obj = pjp.proceed();
if(obj instanceof IFX) {
    IFX ifx = (IFX) obj;
    String statusCode = obj.getPresSvcRs().getBillInqRs().getStatus().getStatusCode();
}
```